# Evaluate $\lim _{n\to \infty }\int_1^2\:\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

We have $$I_n=\int _1^2\:\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}dx$$ and we need to find $\lim _{n\to \infty }I_n$. Have any ideea how we can evaluate this limit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, $\frac{x^n}{x^n+1} \leq 1$ for all $x \in [1,2]$, and the constant function $1$ is integrable in $[1,2]$, so by the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) we have: $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_1^2\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}\,{\rm d}x = \int_1^2 \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{x^n}{x^n+1}\,{\rm d}x = \int_{1}^2 1\,{\rm d}x = 1.$$

Comment: are you sure we can use this method?

Comment: It is clear that $x^n/(x^n + 1) \to 1$. If the convergence was uniform, we could swap $\int$ and $\lim$ right off the bat. But as pointed by Alex in a comment in the other answer, the convergence it not uniform. So we must find another way to swap $\int$ and $\lim$. The Dominated Convergence Theorem was the first thing that came to my mind. I don't know if there is another way to do it without using the definition of integral and start swimming in summations.

Comment: what are the conditions that must be satisfy to use "Dominated Convergence Theorem" ?  for instance, in our case, what conditions were put to use DCT ?

Comment: The statement is: If you have a sequence of integrable functions $f_n$ such that $f_n \to f$, and exists $g$ integrable dominating all of the $f_n$, that is, $|f_n| \leq g$ for all $n \geq 0$, then $\lim \int f_n = \int f$.

Comment: and how I could realize if the convergence is uniform or not? what is the difference, because is saw if the convergence is uniform is same like DCT...

Comment: @Lucas: To show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ one must check that $\lim \limits _n \space \sup \limits _x |f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$. In your problem, though, you get $\frac 1 2$ instead of $0$, so the convergence cannot be uniform. Another way of showing this is the following: the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions must itself be continuous. But in your example, the limit is $0$ on $(1,2]$ and $\frac 1 2$ in $1$, which is discontinuous, so again the convergence cannot be uniform.

Comment: but what is the difference between uniform convergence and dominate convergence? **both have the purpose of changing limit with integral**...I see is same thing ... what give in addition the uniform convergence and when we need to use it and not dominated convergence  ?

Comment: "Dominated Convergence" is not a type of convergence - it is the name of the theorem.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}=1-\frac{1}{x^n+1}$.  Thus,

$$\int_1^2 \frac{x^n}{x^n+1}dx=1-\int_1^2 \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx$$

For $n>1$, the integral on the right-hand side satisfies the inequality

$$\left|\int_1^2 \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx\right|\le \int_1^2 x^{-n}dx=\frac{1-2^{1-n}}{n-1}$$

which clearly goes to zero as $n \to \infty$.

Putting all of this together we see that

$$1\ge \int_1^2 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx=1-\int_1^2 \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx \ge 1-\int_1^2 x^{-n}dx=1-\frac{1-2^{1-n}}{n-1}$$

Therefore, by the "squeeze" theorem

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\int_1^2 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}dx\right) =1$$

Comment: Hi Dr.MV , nice to see you again :D...  about the subject, I think we can prove it with squeeze theorem $\int \:_1^2\:\frac{x^n}{\left(x^n+1\right)}dx\le 1$  but I am thinking to show that $\int \:_1^2\:\frac{x^n}{\left(x^n+1\right)}dx$  is bigger than something goes to 1,have an ideea?

Comment: And you.  Doesn't this development provide the coveted half of such a squeeze?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: A lower bound that tends to 1 as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: they don't provide a lower bound who tends to 1...

Comment: $1-\int_1^2 \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx\ge 1-\int_1^2 x^{-n}dx$.

Comment: @Lucas I added to the answer to provide a proof using the squeeze theorem.  Let me know how I can improve further.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the numerator and denominator of the integrand by $x^n$:
$$ \frac{1}{1+x^{-n}} $$
For every $x \in (1,2]$, $x^{-n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Since this is all but one point of the interval of integration, the integral tends to
$$ \int_1^2 \frac{1}{1} \, dx = 1. $$
To do it more thoroughly than this, you can chop up the interval into a small region around $1$ and the rest, and examine the size of the integrand on each.

Comment: I don't see how you commute the limit with the integral other than with the dominated convergence theorem, which is the answer already given by @IvoTerek. (Note that the convergence is not uniform.)

Comment: The convergence is uniform on intervals $[1+\varepsilon,2]$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, and you can bound the integral on $[1,1+\varepsilon]$ by a constant times $\varepsilon$.

Comment: I totally agree. What I meant is that there is no explicit mention of these facts in your answer. Given that the OP seems to be a beginner, it is important for him to understand that passing to the limit under the integral sign is not a straightforward procedure as it might appear from your answer. It is important to remember that MSE also tries to educate, it is not only a place where problems are solved.

Comment: but what is the difference between uniform convergence and dominate convergence? both have the purpose of changing limit with integral...I see is same thing ... what give in addition the uniform convergence and when we need to use it and not dominated convergence ?

Comment: @Lucas They're very different notions, but happen to coincide for integrating functions over finite intervals. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/ gives an extensive account, but is probably a bit technical. Basically, a sequence of Riemann-integrable functions that converges uniformly on a finite interval converges to a Riemann-integrable function, and the limit and integral can be swapped The DCT is really about the Lebesgue integral. If you want to know more, I suggest you ask a new question - this is not a topic explainable in a few comments.